# Javascript Date object's constructor returns a date one month ahead

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, angular5

I am using typescript (Angular 5) and I have the following code:

```
let date = new Date(2018, 8, 17, 14, 0);
```

I expect "Fri Aug 17 2018 14:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" as the result, but instead this is what it actually returns:

> Mon Sep 17 2018 14:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

As you can see it adds a month to the date. I've fixed it by subtracting like the following code:

```
let date = new Date(2018, 8 - 1, 17, 14, 0);
```

My question is why is this happening? Any idea? Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Months are numbered 0 through 11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not Angular-related, it's just how JavaScript's `Date` works. Months are zero-based: January is `0`, December is `11`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Date object counts months from 0

from "W3Schools"

JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

So just set `7` instead of `8`